# MissingRegistrationForTypes when moving VM to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am moving a VM and its related resouces to another subscription and getting an error.

> {"code":"MissingRegistrationsForTypes","message":"The subscription 'xxx' is not registered for resource types 'Microsoft.Compute/disks (eastus),Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines (eastus)'."}

When I view the Resource Provider status in Azure portal I can see that `Microsoft.Compute` provider is Registred.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

**Update**

I managed to solve this by creating a sample VM in East US region under that subscription, which I am guessing registered the provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For moving resources to another subscription, there are some limitations to that.

1. The source and destination subscriptions must be in the same tenant.
2. The resource provider must be registered in both subscriptions.
3. The account which you use to move the resources must have enough permission.
4. The service must enable the ability to move resources.

The four points above are the most important. For more details, see [Checklist before moving resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#checklist-before-moving-resources).